# How to access a method from the extended abstract class when using it as a type constraint in a method

Tags: flutter, dart, constraints

Say I have this abstract class

```
abstract class Animal{
  static dynamic getSound(){}
}
```

And this other class extending it

```
class Dog extends Animal{
  static dynamic getSound(){
    return "Woof";
  }
}
```

And I want to use a method to access the static method of those classes by sending the type of Animal I want, like this:

```
dynamic getAnimalSound<T extends Animal>(){
  return T.getSound();  
}
```

Except this doesn't work because it isn't assumed that T extends Animal so there I can't access it.

What can I do make this getAnimalSound method working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do in your place is to use [overriding](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-overriding-in-dart/). However, it also only works on non static methods. (untested but should work)

```dart
abstract class Animal{
  dynamic getSound();
}

class Dog extends Animal{
  @override
  dynamic getSound(){
    return "Woof";
  }
}

dynamic getAnimalSound(Animal animal){
  return animal.getSound();  
}
```

Some other tips: (there is nothing wrong with your code though!)

- Dart has special [syntax for getters and setters](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getter-and-setter-methods-in-dart/), so you could rewrite your `getSound()` method to `dynamic get getSound => "Woof"` and `dynamic get getSound;` in `Animal`. Which is a bit cleaner imo.
- If your sounds are just strings, dont use dynamic, use `String` as a return type... It will have better type checking.

Comment: getBreath was an error, my bad! It was supposed to be getSound.

Comment: Your code won't work either though because you're trying to access that method by using a Type T

Comment: Yeah, sorry I was a bit out of practice. However, you don't need a type parameter at all! You just say that the thing you want to have the sound from is an animal, doesn't matter which. If you give it a dog, dart will call the getSound method inside of the dog. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: FYI: If you want to test it out quickly, https://dartpad.dev is great for that.